# Ruby ODBC Error 37000 (102) Sql syntax error

Tags: sql, ruby, sql-server, null, syntax-error

I have the following ruby database insert using ODBC. Connection is fine.

```
 dbh.do( "INSERT INTO prowlerRunningResults(ProwlerDriver, SourceURL, Title, DestinationURL, FileSource, FileType, FileName, LastModified, FileSize, HashMD5, HashSHA256, ImageBinary) 
            VALUES (#{driver}, #{source}, #{title}, 'NA', #{imgSrc},  #{fileType},  #{fileName},  #{lastModified}, #{fileSize},   #{md},   #{sha},   #{binary}   )" )
```

However, I am getting an `Error message: 37000 (102) [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near ','.` Which could be a little more helpful considering the number of commas involved. Nevertheless, having looked and looked I simple can't see the problem !!

So to the questions:

1. Can you detect the syntax error that is being reported?
2. I would like to insert NULL instead of 'NA' - but have no idea how to do that in ruby. How is it done?

EDIT: 
Could be a problem with the DB Schema.
The physical DB has FileSize as an int. So I updated the code to insert #{fileSize.to_i} but the ImageBinary is a varbinary(MAX) - perhaps I could write the file out as HEX to a string? What do you think?

Comment: Try doing a puts or raise of the string to see what the SQL resolves to.  Most likely you need some single quotes around your string values.

Comment: @MarlinPierce convert your comment to an answer - and you get the points. I had indeed forgot the blooming quotes !!

Comment: Isn't there something in the interface for using placeholders? String interpolation for building SQL is so 1998.

Comment: @muistooshort not sure - don't know of anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

To debug, try looking at the expanded string.  You can puts, log, or raise.

```
sql = "INSERT INTO prowlerRunningResults(ProwlerDriver, SourceURL, Title, DestinationURL, FileSource, FileType, FileName, LastModified, FileSize, HashMD5, HashSHA256, ImageBinary) 
        VALUES (#{driver}, #{source}, #{title}, 'NA', #{imgSrc},  #{fileType},  #{fileName},  #{lastModified}, #{fileSize},   #{md},   #{sha},   #{binary}   )"
puts sql
logger.info sql
raise sql
```

You probably forgot some single quotes for some string data.